# Kubernetes populate with base image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume

Docker supports named volumes and those volumes are populated with the base image content when mounted.

I need the same for K8s, i.e. I need that a pod will populate a volume with the contents of the base image.

Is that possible with K8s and PVC?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you want to mount a local volume into your Docker image. That is, the local folder is mounted as a volume inside the Docker image.

You can mount a local directory in your Docker container using volume `hostPath`

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#hostpath

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
```

Note that since your container could be deployed on ANY node, that means the hostPath must be available on any node, with the same content, if you want to have reproducible behavior.

In short, this is not meant to mount local data that you interact with, but rather things like libraries, certificates or similar.

As an alternative, you might want to consider using [Secrets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/) to mount small amount of data into your Pods.

Comment: Thank you. But are the mounts populated with the contents of the base image? The background of my question is that I try to deploy Zimbra as a Docker container, and the Zimbra installation must modify files in /var and /etc, as well as /opt/zimbra. The configuration files must be shared between containers. The easiest way is to use named mounts in plain Docker.

Comment: if you mount a `hostPath` folder, you have access to the content, but as thedoc mentions: "the directories created on the underlying hosts are only writable by root. You either need to run your process as root in a privileged container or modify the file permissions on the host to be able to write to a hostPath volume".

Comment: In any case, this is not what you should do on Kubernetes, because there is no guarantee that your Pods will all land on the same host (you could force it with DaemonSets or specific selectors, but that defeats the purpose of using Kubernetes)

Comment: If the config is static (all hosts use the same config) then you should simply have it in the base image. If the config needs to be editied before running (i.e. it needs to be aware of the IP of the other nodes) then you should run a script that will look up the IP of these nodes from a Service to edit your config before startup, or use a sidecar container to do this task, because this will need to be ran on every Pod whenever a Pod is scaled up or down. (i.e. you need to do service discovery yourself if Zimbra doesn't do it for you.)